# How to configure Apache Webserver to load GIF

Tags: apache-httpd, webserver, html

I would like to understand how can i configure Apache webserver in a way that whenever someone sends a http request it should just load a 1x1 Pixel Gif..

Currently, response that we get is the text configured index.html in (/var/www/html)..

I tried Putting the image Source in index.html but it didnt work..

---

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do something like redirect the `index.html` in home page to a `Gif` in another location.

Then, put below code in the index.html as per your convenience

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moving to Image</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh"CONTENT="1;URL=http://domain.com/folder/sample.gif">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
```